# onClick event fails to perform function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image within my program that I want the user to be able to rotate 90 degrees with each click. Because the image is automatically placed in my program at a tilted angle, I needed to use CSS to rotate the image before allowing the user to do so. This way, as it is clicked, the image will appear horizontally and sideways. Currently, the onClick event in my HTML code appears to only be working once.

I have attempted declaring a variable to increase the rotational value at each click but doing this removed the rotation altogether

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
     var degrees = 57;
     function rotateImage() {
       var img = document.getElementById('c-channel');
       degrees += 90;
       img.style.transform = 'rotate(degrees)';  
 }
 </script>

 <style>
    #c-channel{
      position: absolute;
      cursor:move;
      width:190px;
      height:150px;
      transform:rotate(57deg);
   }
   </style>
   </head>

 <body>
   <img id="c-channel" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2a39b17c-6b95-46ec9d5c-cf9db18cd879%2Foutput-onlinepngtools%20(6).png?v=1564485433523" onclick="rotateImage()"> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I expected the program to allow the user to rotate the image another 90 degrees with every click but instead, clicking the image provides no visible change.

Comment: `img.style.transform = 'rotate(degrees)'; `-- Does this work properly? I do not think the degrees would be replaced with the  value in the code you provided.

Comment: Change to img.style.transform = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the `degrees` variable, you can use string template as follows:

```js
var degrees = 57;

function rotateImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById('c-channel');
  degrees = (degrees % 360) + 90;
  //img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
  img.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
}
```

```css
#c-channel {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(57deg);
  border: grey;
}
```

```html
<img id="c-channel" onclick="rotateImage()">
```

Comment: Gah! Beat me to it by 8 seconds :)

Comment: I would also put in a `degrees %= 360` to wrap the value back around to the valid interval. It still works above 360 degrees of course, but I could see that value getting unnecessarily large after several rotations. I know this is based on the OP's code, I'm just thinking perhaps they didn't consider that. It's small, albeit.

Answer (score 2):

You are using degrees as a string rather than the actual value, and you also need to append a unit next to it.

```js
var degrees = 57;
var img = document.getElementById('c-channel');

function rotateImage() {
  degrees += 90;
  img.style.transform = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)';
}
```

```css
#c-channel {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(57deg);
}
```

```html
<img id="c-channel" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2a39b17c-6b95-46ec9d5c-cf9db18cd879%2Foutput-onlinepngtools%20(6).png?v=1564485433523" onclick="rotateImage()">
```